# Pegar primeira linha e primeira coluna gridview JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou tentando pegar o valor da primeira linha e da primeira coluna do gridview através do javascript, porém está retornando erro.
Segue como estou tentando fazer:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("#<%=GridView12.ClientID %>");
var cell = grid.rows[parseInt(selectedRowIndex) + 1].cells[0];
var hidID = cell.childNodes[0];
document.getElementById('textcodigo').value = hidID;
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Consegui chegar neste código:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("<%=GridView12.ClientID %>");
var cell = grid.rows[0].cells[0];
var hidID = cell.childNodes[0];
document.getElementById('textcodigo').value = hidID;
```

Porém em textcodigo aparece [object Text].
Preciso da primeira linha, da primeira coluna.

Este é o meu GridView12:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView12" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="identificador" CellPadding="4" CssClass="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="GridView12_RowDeleting1">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="identificador" HeaderText="Identificador" SortExpression="identificador"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Excluir" OnClientClick="return confirm('Deseja excluir o identificador selecionado?');"></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

E cheguei nesta função, porém ele continua me retornando undefined.

```js
var grid = document.getElementById("<%=GridView12.ClientID %>");
var cellPivot;

if (grid.rows.length > 0) {

  var theDropdown = grid.rows[0].cells[0].text;
  document.getElementById('textcodigo').value = theDropdown;

}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` não conseguiu capturar um elemento com o `ID` informado, isso porque você está usando `#`.

Comment: Tirando o #, retornou outro erro. "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedRowIndex is not defined"

Comment: Sinal que funcionou e o outro agora está na linha subsequente. O erro diz que a variável `selectedRowIndex` não existe, ou seja, não foi declarada antes dessa linha.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr eu preciso pegar a primeira linha, e a primeira coluna, posso pegar var cell = grid.rows[0].cells[0];
                var hidID = cell.childNodes[0].text;  mas ainda sim está retornando erro, não aparece o valor correto. Está aparecendo undefined.

Comment: Você pode tentar um `for` ou `foreach` para percorrer todos os valores que você quer. Como o trecho do código é pequeno, não temos ideia do elemento.

Comment: Verifique se esta thread pode te ajudar:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724146/1272142

Comment: Eu preciso apenas da primeira linha, e da primeira coluna. Não preciso de um for ou foreach. Mas não está dando, agora aparece assim no textcodigo: [object Text]

Comment: @ValdeirPsr editei com o código que cheguei, porém ainda não está passando o valor da primeira coluna e da primeira linha.

Comment: Você pode usar `hidID.textContent`, `hidID.innerHTML`, `hidID.outerHTML` para capturar o valor do elemento `cell.childNodes[0]`

Comment: O retorno que ele me trás em textcodigo é UNDEFINED. Não está trazendo nenhum valor.

Comment: Isso aqui `document.getElementById('textcodigo').value;` está retornando `[object Text]`?

Comment: @dvd sim, e quando eu coloco o innerHTML ele retorna undefined.

Comment: Ele é um GridView

Comment: @dvd eu estou pegando a primeira coluna, da primeira linha do grid, e quero atribuir a esse value, só que não está dando certo.  Preciso desses dados e jogar no textcodigo.

Comment: Esse grid é um html?

Comment: @dvd, sim, de todas as formas que tento pegar o valor, me retorna undefined. Todos os exemplos que me baseio, me retorna este valor.

Comment: Tem como mostrar esse HTML, apenas até a parte do que vc quer pegar?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código do GridView12 e com as alterações da função. Obrigado.